# How to make smaller and more controlled acceleration increments on a 2009 Yamaha R6?

Tags: yamaha

When doing really low speed turns in the city road I would really feel more confident if the bike would increase its acceleration beginning from idle in a really slow or controlled way, instead of having the bike increasing the acceleration abruptly.

You can see the bike in idle in https://youtube.com/shorts/XmmSsJ3o2Rs?feature=share.

And in https://youtube.com/shorts/sjr1tu5WoOk?feature=share you can see three (really hard to make and squeezing the throttle grip as slow as humanly possible) attempts to increase the acceleration in the slower way possible, but anyway, it seems impossible to go to 1500-1750 RPMs as the bike always jumps directly to around 2k RPMs.

Is there a way to make the acceleration starting from idle to increment in a more slower or controlled way to avoid the uncomfortable abrupt acceleration changes in slow speed corners?

Comment: Welcome to Mechanics - This is a driving technique question, which is off topic here, but you'll find it comes with practice. Remember, going to 2k rpm is not a big jump at all - on that bike you will spend most of your time up at much higher RPM. What is key is learning clutch control

Comment: Or of course you could get a bike that doesn't accelerate as fast - and R6 is a fast bike. Now I'm older, I moved off sport bikes and onto a Harley because it is much more controllable - it isn't a racer, just a comfortable cruiser.